# Soundcloud javascript sdk connect() is intercepted on mobile by the android native app

Tags: javascript, android, sdk, soundcloud

I'm testing on localhost and using chrome inspect for port forwarding to my android phone. Connecting works fine when the native Soundcloud app isn't installed, but if it is then the connect redirect gets caught and the native app just notifies that "There was a problem loading that URL". Is there a way to work around this?